# jade: if statements and nesting

Tags: pug

Concider this pseudo-ish server side code

```
if(isFixed) {
  <div class="fixed">
} else {
  <div>
}
    <p>Inner element</p>
  </div>
```

I try to do this in jade but...

```
 - if(mode === 'fixed') {
   div#tabbar
 - }
     p ...I cannot get this to be an inner element :(
```

It always renders like this, with the `</div>` closed:

```
<div id="tabbar"></div><p>I want this inside of the div</p>
```

Am I messing up the indention?
Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to separate control flow from the template. Try this:

```
divClass = null

if isFixed
   divClass = "fixed"

div(class=divClass)
   p inner element
```

Which in turn might suggest factoring out the "isFixed" parameter into the actual divClass parameter to be passed on. But that depends on your remaining code/template of course.

---

As an alternative, try a mixin:

```
mixin content
  p inner element

if (isFixed)
  div(class="test")
    mixin content
else
  div(class="other")
    mixin content
```

Comment: sure, in this particular case (class=tabClass) is exactly what I'm doing. But I'm asking more in general if the sort of thing in my example is possible at all. E.g. instead of my <div> let's say I had 5 different tags with 10 different attributes in my if statement.

Comment: I don't believe it is possible to keep the indentation level from inside a previous IF. From a subjective point of view, this could make things difficult to follow and confusing. I have updated my answer with a mixin approach, which might be a variant closer to your case.

Comment: That sounds reasonable. The mixin approach looks much cleaner.

Comment: you can also assign the class inline `div(class=(isFixed?'test':'other'))` without needing a mixin

Answer (score 9):

I would approach this with a ternary (or fully written out conditional or method) to determine the class attribute. That allows you to keep the div on one line and keeps indentation like it would be for any other element:

```
div(class="#{ isFixed ? 'fixed' : '' }")
    p Inner Element
```

Comment: I reckon this is the least cluttered way.

Answer (score 2):

Jade doesn't seem to have a built in solution to start and end the tags other than utilizing the 'pipe' character to render plain text.

```
- if(mode === 'fixed') {
| <div id="tabbar">
- }
| <p>I cannot get this to be an inner element :(</p>
- if(mode === 'fixed') {
| </div>
- }
```

Less cluttered solution -

```
div(class=(isFixed) ? 'fixed' : '')
  p inner element
```