# How to go around the lack of endif in jade

Tags: javascript, json, pug

Is there any way to do something like this?

```
ul.categories
- var categories = [];
each ingredient in mv.data.recipe.ingredients
  if !categories.includes(ingredient.categoryId)
    - categories.push(ingredient.categoryId);
    li.category #{ingredient.categoryName}
      ul.ingredients
  - // endif?
        li.ingredient #{ingredient.number} #{ingredient.unitName} #{ingredient.name}
```

Without the `endif?` comment the code works for the first ingredient in every category since it gets caught by the `if` statement.

So can this be solved with `mixin`, `extend` or some such? A `endif` would solve it but Jade doesn't have a end keyword for anything, afaik.

Or will I have to resort to using HTML in my jade file?

**mv.data.recipe**:

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Hellmann's hamburgare med hemmagjort br\u00f6d",
    "description": "I v\u00e4rldens godaste hamburgerbr\u00f6d finns en hemlig ingrediens som ingen av dina g\u00e4ster kommer att kunna lista ut; Hellmann's majonn\u00e4s! Prova sj\u00e4lv och uppt\u00e4ck hur saftiga och l\u00e4ckra Hellmann's hamburgerbr\u00f6d blir!",
    "instructions": "<p>Hamburgerbr\u00f6den:<br\/>1. S\u00e4tt ugnen p\u00e5 200 grader. Blanda j\u00e4sten och vattnet (fingervarmt). Hacka chilin. Blanda sedan i mj\u00f6l, Hellmann\u2019s majonn\u00e4s, timjan, chili, socker och ost. Kn\u00e5da degen p\u00e5 medelhastighet i 10 min, blanda sedan ner&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;salt och blanda i ca tv\u00e5 minuter till. <br\/>2. L\u00e5t degen j\u00e4sa 20-30 min eller till dubbel storlek.<br\/>3. Forma bullar till \u00f6nskad storlek och l\u00e5t j\u00e4sa till dubbla storleken under en duk. <br\/>4. Pensla med lite mj\u00f6lk och toppa med sesamfr\u00f6n. Baka av i ca 10 min eller tills dom f\u00e5tt en fin gyllengul f\u00e4rg.<br\/><br\/>Tillbeh\u00f6r:<br\/>1. Skiva r\u00f6dl\u00f6k och tomat. St\u00e4ll fram en sk\u00e5l med Hellmann's majonn\u00e4s och ett paket med skivad cheddarost.<br\/><br\/>Hellmann's hamburgare:<br\/>1. Stoppa allt utom f\u00e4rsen (Anv\u00e4nd g\u00e4rna h\u00f6grevsf\u00e4rs f\u00f6r b\u00e4sta smakupplevelse) i en matberedare och mixa till det \u00e4r sm\u00e5 bitar kvar av allt. Blanda det med h\u00f6grevsf\u00e4rsen och forma till hamburgare. <br\/>2. Stek burgarna medium och servera med en skiva tomat, l\u00f6kringar, cheddarost och en klick majonn\u00e4s i ett Hellmann\u2019s hamburgerbr\u00f6d.<\/p>",
    "src": "\/uploads\/images\/recipes\/recipe-1.jpg",
    "minutes": "60",
    "author": null,
    "rating": "2.599999999985",
    "ingredients": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Vatten",
            "optional": 1,
            "number": 4,
            "unitName": "dl",
            "unitMultiplier": 0.1,
            "categoryId": 1,
            "categoryName": "Hellmann's hamburgerbr\u00f6d"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Vetemj\u00f6l",
            "optional": 1,
            "number": 500,
            "unitName": "g",
            "unitMultiplier": 1,
            "categoryId": 1,
            "categoryName": "Hellmann's hamburgerbr\u00f6d"
        }
        ...snip...
    ]
}
```

Here's what I want to achive in HTML:

```
<ul class="categories">
    <li class="category">Hellmann's hamburgerbröd
        <ul class="ingredients">
            <li class="ingredient">4 dl Vatten</li>
            <li class="ingredient">500 g Vetemjöl</li>
            <li class="ingredient">50 g Jäst</li>
            <li class="ingredient">100 g Majonnäs</li>
            <li class="ingredient">25 g Strösocker</li>
            <li class="ingredient">10 g Salt Fint</li>
            <li class="ingredient">50 g Riven Ost</li>
            <li class="ingredient">2 msk Timjan</li>
            <li class="ingredient">1 msk Chilipeppar Röd</li>
            <li class="ingredient">0.5 dl Sesamfrö</li>
            <li class="ingredient">1 dl Mjölk</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="category">Hellmann's hamburgare
        <ul class="ingredients">
            <li class="ingredient">1 st Gul lök</li>
            <li class="ingredient">250 g Bacon Skivat</li>
            <li class="ingredient">3 klyftor Vitlök</li>
            <li class="ingredient">1 msk Oxfond Buljong</li>
            <li class="ingredient">1.5 msk Rökt paprikapulver</li>
            <li class="ingredient">1 kg Köttfärs - Nöt</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="category">Tillbehör
        <ul class="ingredients">
            <li class="ingredient">2 st Rödlök</li>
            <li class="ingredient">200 g Cheddarost i Skivor</li>
            <li class="ingredient">2 st Tomater</li>
            <li class="ingredient">100 g Majonnäs</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jade: if statements and nesting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14415448/jade-if-statements-and-nesting)

Comment: I don't know Jade, but can't you just pull the indentation back? Like in the first example on http://jade-lang.com/demo/

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit But then the `li` wouldn't be a child of the `ul`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Jade is indentation sensitive, I want the `li.ingredient`element to be a child of `ul.ingredients`.

Comment: You have a missing comma in `"rating": "2.599999999985"`

Comment: Maybe you should explain your problem in some other way than showing code that doesn't solve it.

Comment: @red woops, manually pasted that together, forgot to put it there..

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Essentially I want to break up the array of ingredients under different categories while not repeating the category for every ingredient or getting the ingredients and categories on the same level. I want to print out the category tags when a new category is reached and then ignore it for the rest of the ingredients in that category.

Comment: So what's wrong with just terminating the conditional as I proposed. Remove indentation = endif

Comment: That would give me `<ul><li>Category<ul></ul></li><li>Ingredient</li><li>Ingredient</li></ul> ` rather than `<ul><li>Category<ul><li>Ingredient</li><li>Ingredient</li></ul></li></ul> `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Complete rewrite as I misunderstood the question as originally posted.

Perform the grouping before Jade.

```
var categories = {};
mv.data.recipe.ingredients.forEach(function(ingredient) {
  if (!categories[ingredient.categoryName]) {
    categories[ingredient.categoryName] = [];
  }
  categories[ingredient.categoryName].push(ingredient);
});
```

then give `categories` to Jade. From there it's easy:

```
ul.categories
  each categoryName, ingredients in categories
    li.category #{categoryName}
      ul.ingredients
        each ingredient in ingredients
          li.ingredient #{ingredient.number} #{ingredient.unitName} #{ingredient.name}
```

(This is a shortcut that assumes no two categories have the same name; if that is not true, you might want to have one object `categories` that maps ids to category names, and another `categoryIngredients` that maps category ids to array of ingredients as above. The logic is not much more complex.)

Comment: True I don't like my current solution either, but since your solution doesn't actually solve the problem. I don't really have much to go on other than potentially looping through all ingredients for every ingredient. And having an if statement to check if it's the same category. Maybe I would be better of restructuring the JSON somehow?

Comment: If this doesn't solve your problem, then I misunderstood your problem. Please give the desired output markup, and describe in words what you want to happen. (Actually Lightness Races in Orbit said it well: Maybe you should explain your problem in some other way than showing code that doesn't solve it)

Comment: I added the output I want to the question.

Comment: Didn't get a notification about this edit, but this is a much better solution, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well here is one way of doing it, not as elegant; but it will have to do for now. I'll leave the question open for a few days in case anyone has a prettier way of doing this. Or if I find a better solution myself.

```
ul.categories
  - var categories = [];
  each ingredient in mv.data.recipe.ingredients
    if !categories.includes(ingredient.categoryId)
      if categories.length > 0
        </ul></li>
      - categories.push(ingredient.categoryId);
      <li class="category">#{ingredient.categoryName}<ul class="ingredients">
    li.ingredient #{ingredient.number} #{ingredient.unitName} #{ingredient.name}
  </ul></li>
```

Answer (score -1):

As shown in the first example on [the Jade demo page](http://jade-lang.com/demo/), there is no need for an "endif" because control flow is (at least partially) denoted by indentation.

So just pull your indentation back in.